# Entity Framework Exclude Fields Query Count and POCO best way

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, poco

I created a `qr` object to get total item count without getting all data from database and also if necessary to select `MyViewModel` list

```
var qr = dbSet.Select(o => 
                          new { ParentID = o.Parent.ID, o.Parent.Name, o.ID})
.Select(o => new MyViewModel(o.ParentID, o.Name, o.ID));
```

But when I tried `qr.Count()` and `qr.ToList()` they all run same query in database which is for items not only for items' count.

What is the best and fastest way to get 'MyViewModel' items' itself or items' count or both at the same time?

Comment: The query only goes as far as `.AsEnumerable()` since that is what the method is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this query is because it calls a constructor of MyViewModel in

```
.Select(o => new MyViewModel(o.ParentID, o.Name, o.ID))
```

This call effectively converts your IQueryable to IEnumerable, as it is not possible to call a constructor from a query.

To avoid this conversion, use object initializer instead of constructor:

```
.Select(o => new MyViewModel 
        { 
            ParentID = o.ParentID, 
            Name = o.Name, 
            ID = o.ID
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `.AsEnumerable()` call in your linq query. That means that any translate-your-query-into-SQL stops right there, and anything after will not be translated to SQL. Therefore, the only query that will be run in your database is the retrieval of you complete `dbSet`. If you want to only retrieve the count, than run the following linq query

```
var qrCount = dbSet.Count();
```

Comment: But what if I have `where` filter after last select.